# How to resolve ModuleNotFoundError when compiling

Tags: dependencies, compiling

I am fairly new to Ubuntu (and Unix) and ran into an issue when installing a Python version through PyEnv. When running the install command, I got a few errors in the form of:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Clearly there were dependencies which needed to be downloaded, but I am not clear on how you should go about getting these dependencies, based off of the error messages displayed. Looking Online I found a reference on PyEnv's wiki that you should install dependencies with

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev curl \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
```

which fixed the errors. However, note that this does not target a package named `_bz2`, instead the package's name is `libbz2-dev`. The other missing libraries were also reported with different names.

What is the steps one should take to determine what packages are required to resolve ModuleNotFoundError's when the names reported do not match the package you should download? (Next time I would prefer to not depend on getting lucky when googling...)